# Missing unicode character in terminal

Tags: unicode, terminal, fonts, terminator

I am missing these Unicode characters in my terminal (among others)

ℹ: U+2139 
☰: U+2630

**Terminal:** Terminator 
**Font:** Hack Nerd Font Mono Regular

**Example:**
[Terminal section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKrwa.png)

Answer (score 0):

If [this is the font file you're talking about](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/blob/master/patched-fonts/Hack/Regular/complete/Hack%20Regular%20Nerd%20Font%20Complete%20Mono.ttf), then the answer is quite simple: that file doesn't contain a glyph for U+2630:

```
$ otfinfo -u Hack\ Regular\ Nerd\ Font\ Complete\ Mono.ttf  | grep uni2630
$
```

Comment: Oh ok. that would explain it XD
I guess I'm gonna have to find a new font.